# Datetime format for text/plain messages (or parts)

Tags: http, multipartform-data

I'd like to send datetime data as part of an HTTP message (req or resp, doesn't matter). If I sent that data as part of a `text/plain` message, what format should I use for the datetime value? [RFC7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-7.1.1.1) specifies HTTP format for *header* values but I can't find any specs or even doc on this.

I think my choices are the HTTP date format as above or [ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). I had considered using `application/json` but dates are not primitive types there, even though ISO is a commonly-accepted format.

Which should I use? Any why would be good too. FWIW, I'm tending to the ISO format.

The `multipart/form-data` below shows an example of each

```
--eab10e2a-3ae9-cb83-3b14-6627f8c57298
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="date_as_iso-date"

2018-04-24T21:23:42.341-04:00
--eab10e2a-3ae9-cb83-3b14-6627f8c57298
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="date_as_http-date"

Wed, 25 Apr 2018 01:46:42 GMT
--eab10e2a-3ae9-cb83-3b14-6627f8c57298--
```

Comment: Dates sent here are not part of HTTP protocol, but are part of higher application layer. As such, you are free to choose whatever format you like. I'd choose the format which is the easiest to parse with the language/library that will receive these messages.

Comment: @gudok Yes-but ... it's HTTP so I don't have control over (all) the clients. And in my mind that's what Content-Type helps define. I 'spose I could use a text/vnd.iso-date+plain or similar Content-Type.